# What is the best type of insulation to use on a hinged metal attic door?

Tags: insulation, doors, attic, energy-efficiency, attic-door

What is the best type of insulation to use on a hinged metal attic door (no integrated ladder)?

Primarily concerned about heat entry through the door when closed.

Also concerned about heat entry around the edges of the door when closed.

Would like to use something that does not cause a mess when the attic door is opened.

Comment: Re: your followup question - this really is not that much hassle to remove/replace - it's a lightweight box that takes literally seconds to set aside/in place (and if you have a day with a lot of traffic into the attic, you can set it aside at the start of the traffic and only replace it at the end of the traffic.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks. It's more of a "where to put this thing" issue.  The only places to put it are covered in exposed fiberglass.  Of course, changing that could be another small project.

Answer (score 3):

A rigid foam (or ductboard) box in the attic which sits over (is larger than) the door opening. When you open the door, the box is still there. When you enter the attic you lift the box out of the way. When you are done in the attic, you lift the box back into position over the door, then close the door.

Comment: agreed. google "attic hatch insulation" and click on images for lots of ideas.