# Insulation type to use on a hinged metal attic door

Tags: insulation, doors, attic, energy-efficiency, attic-door

In [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/64493), I asked about the best type of insulation to use on a hinged metal attic door, when one is also concerned about heat entering around the edges of the door when closed.

The answer I received is a good one (and provides an answer to *that* question as it was asked), but adds an extra step to entering the attic.  If I may, I would also like to ask the separate question of when one is ***not*** concerned about the edges of the door, but just concerned about the lack of insulation of the door itself.  So...

What is the best type of insulation to use on a hinged metal attic door (no integrated ladder)?

Only concerned about heat entry through the door when closed.

Would like something that does not cause a mess when the door is opened, and does not add extra steps to entering the attic.  I'm thinking along the lines of something added to the metal door itself.  There are a number of choices, and I'm wondering what type of product is best.

Comment: Why not edit the original question instead of asking a new one? I would just use rigid foam and some caulk/liquid nails/silicone to attach it.

Comment: @user20127 Because someone already spent their time answering that question, and changing the question after the fact would not be respectful to the time they spent.  Also, I'm not sure which direction is best, so I am interested in learning answers to both questions.

Comment: @user20127... post your comment as an answer and I'll up-vote it, because that's what I would use.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Can rigid foam insulation be cut with hand tools?  Is any safety gear needed?

Comment: Can be easily cut to size using a common utility knife, flooring/carpet knife. I have even seen craftsmen use a long blade kitchen knife to cut the thicker varieties. Sheets are often 4' x 8' from 1/2" to 2" thick. Use a dust mask, safety glasses, and gloves.

Answer (score 1):

One recommendation is to use rigid foam insulation attached with caulking, liquid nails, or silicone.

Answer (score 0):

Use rigid foam. You can cut it with a circular saw, or with a utility knife. Buy a 2 inch sheet that's R13, you an always double it up to get R26. Measure the size you need and cut with a circular saw, it cuts like butter. Make 2 and then attach to each other and the door with silicone.

You will still possibly have issues with air leakage around the door, but that's the best you can do attached to the door itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dense Packed Denim With Breathable  Reflective Insulation On Both Sides Of The Denim. I'm not referring to a radiant barrier.